# Pass Raw XML for YQL query

Tags: json, xml, yql

I am looking to pass my own xml to YQL to parse into JSON, rather than having Yahoo's servers query the URL I provide to get the XML.

Current request where Yahoo queries the page I provide to get a JSON response:

```
queue_request({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
    data: {
        q: 'select * from xml where url="' + url + '"',
        format: 'json'
    },
    complete: callback
})
```

I would like to do something along the lines of (pseudo code):

```
queue_request({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
    data: {
        q: 'select * from xml where xmlstring="' + xml + '"',
        format: 'json'
    },
    complete: callback
})
```

In order to avoid yahoo making a request to a server.
Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible using the built-in YQL tables (e.g. `xml`). 
However, it is possibly by making use of a [custom Open Data Table](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-creating-opentables-chapter.html).

**Custom data table**

You can create a custom table and use an [`<execute>` block to execute some JavaScript](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-execute-chapter.html) that parses the XML string provided in the query and makes the resulting XML object be the result from the query.

```
...
<select itemPath="" produces="XML">
  <inputs>
    <key id="xmlstring" type="xs:string" paramType="variable" required="true"/>
  </inputs>
  <execute><![CDATA[
    response.object = new XML(xmlstring);
  ]]></execute>
</select>
...
```

» See [the full example data table](https://github.com/salathe/yql-tables/blob/examples/data/xmlstringarg.xml)

**Example query**

Now that there is a custom table, we can [use](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-opentables-import.html) it in a query.

```
use "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/salathe/yql-tables/examples/data/xmlstringarg.xml" as xml;
select * from xml where xmlstring="<example><a>A</a><b>B</b></example>";
```

» See [this query in the YQL console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=use%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fsalathe%2Fyql-tables%2Fexamples%2Fdata%2Fxmlstringarg.xml%22%20as%20xml%3B%0Aselect%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20xmlstring%3D%22%3Cexample%3E%3Ca%3EA%3C%2Fa%3E%3Cb%3EB%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Fexample%3E%22%3B)

**Your code example**

Really, only the query itself has changed to include the `use` statement.

```
var query = 'use "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/salathe/yql-tables/examples/data/xmlstringarg.xml" as xml;'
          + 'select * from xml where xmlstring="' + xml + '"';
queue_request({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
    data: {
        q: query,
        format: 'json'
    },
    complete: callback
})
```

**Links**

- [Open Data Tables Reference](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-opentables-reference.html)
- [Executing JavaScript in Open Data Tables](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-execute-chapter.html)
- Bonus link: [YQL Editor](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/editor/) where you can edit/save your own custom data tables (I used GitHub above, but you don't have to).